# Migrate Users ASP.NET Web Pages tables to MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

**Info**
I want to 'upgrade' my ASP.NET Web Page project to an ASP.NET MVC project by just starting over, it are only a few pages and it would be good for learning.

**The Issue**
The current project holds a few users for authentication
ASP.NET made a few tables in my database:

- Roles
- Profiles
- Users
- ...

But when I use the MVC Project I see it makes different tables for authentication:

- AspNetUserLogins
- AspNetUserRoles
- AspNetUser
- ...

**The Question**
How do I migrate my users or how do I tell ASP.net to use the old tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this [site](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/SimpleMembershipSchemeUpdateMigration/SimpleMembershipToIdentityMigration.sql) thanks to [this blog](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.be/)

And edited to fit my needs:

```
    /****** Object: Table [dbo].[AspNetRoles] Script Date: 11/14/2013 1:56:03 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AspNetUserRoles', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AspNetUserLogins', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AspNetUserClaims', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AspNetRoles', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AspNetUsers', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc]           DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [CreateDate]                              DATETIME       NULL,
    [ConfirmationToken]                       NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [IsConfirmed]                             BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [LastPasswordFailureDate]                 DATETIME       NULL,
    [PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess]        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [PasswordChangedDate]                     DATETIME       NULL,
    [PasswordVerificationToken]               NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate] DATETIME       NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] (
    [Id]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] (
    [UserId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RoleId]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]([RoleId] ASC);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]([UserId] ASC);
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] (
    [UserId]        NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [LoginProvider] ASC, [ProviderKey] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]([UserId] ASC);
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] (
    [Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [UserId]    NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_User_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User_Id]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]([UserId] ASC);
GO

INSERT INTO AspNetUsers(Id, UserName, PasswordHash, SecurityStamp,
CreateDate, ConfirmationToken, IsConfirmed, LastPasswordFailureDate, PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess,
PasswordChangedDate, PasswordVerificationToken, PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate,AccessFailedCount,LockoutEndDateUtc)
SELECT Users.UserId, Users.UserName, Memberships.Password, 
Memberships.PasswordSalt,  CreateDate, 
null, 1, '1/1/1977', 0,
'1/1/2017', null, '1/1/2100',0,'1/1/1977'
FROM Users
LEFT OUTER JOIN Memberships ON Users.UserId = Memberships.UserId
GO

INSERT INTO AspNetRoles(Id, Name)
SELECT RoleId, RoleName
FROM Roles
GO

INSERT INTO AspNetUserRoles(UserId, RoleId)
SELECT UserId, RoleId
FROM UsersInRoles
GO

--INSERT INTO AspNetUserLogins(UserId, LoginProvider, ProviderKey)
--SELECT UserId, Provider, ProviderUserId
--FROM Memberships
--GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Greetings you may want to start with Database first Approach in `MVC-Core` but its little bit different from what you have seen so far, let me explain the steps for adding your database:

- Install Entity Framework:

Run `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

To enable reverse engineering from an existing database we need to install a couple of other packages too.

1. Run Install-Package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre`
2. Run Install-Package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`
3. Run Install-Package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design`

Now Reverse engineer your model:

- Run the following command to create a model from the existing
  database. If you receive an error stating the term
  'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, then
  close and reopen Visual Studio.

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`

The reverse engineer process created entity classes and a derived context based on the schema of the existing database. The entity classes are simple C# objects that represent the data you will be querying and saving. And now you can create a `DbContext` class and start using your database, so far you issue about database is over, and now i suggest you read about [Identity In Asp.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity).